# addSubview pushed my view down

Tags: ios

I changed my code from `self.view = m_tabBarController.view;` to `[self.view addSubview:m_tabBarController.view];` and my view seems to be pushed down. Why is that so?

m_tabBarController is UITabBarController.

No idea why that happened. Need some guidance.. Thanks

Comment: addSubview method adds the subview to the end of the parent’s list of subviews.

Comment: then what should be the correct statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this in front of the [self.view addSubview:m_tabBarController.view];

```
m_tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

these two functions are for different purpose.

in this

```
self.view = m_tabBarController.view;
```

you are assigning m_tabBarController.view to self.view

and in this

```
[self.view addSubview:m_tabBarController.view];
```

you are adding m_tabBarController.view on self.view

then ofcource your view will be down in this function because your self.view have become parent for m_tabBarController.view.

Thanks

Comment: if i run self.view = m_tabBarController.view; in ios6, it gives me UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency issue. but the addSubview works fine in iOS6...